# Incorrect Number of parameters for Function IF(), Expected 3, received 4

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-flow

Error Received in Flow when creating a formula resource
The formula expression is invalid: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 4

IF({!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}<= 6000,500,
IF(AND({!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}>6000,{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}<= 24000),{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}*0,08,
IF(AND({!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}>24000,{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}<= 32000),{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}*0.1,
IF(AND({!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}>3200,{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}<=40000),{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}*0.12,
IF(AND({!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}>40000,{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}<=46667),{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}*0.15,
IF({!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}>46667, 7000, 0
)
)
)
)
)
)

Keep receiving this error, I have double checked all true false logic

Answer (score 0):

`{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}*0,08,` looks fishy. Why do you bother multiplying by zero.

You meant to put a decimal point but Salesforce treated the comma as next `IF` argument separator?

```
IF(
    {!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}<= 6000,
    500, 
    IF(
        AND({!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}>6000,{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}<= 24000),
        {!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}*0.08,
        IF(
            AND({!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}>24000,{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}<= 32000),
            {!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}*0.1, 
            IF(
                AND({!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}>3200,{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}<=40000),
                {!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}*0.12,
                IF(
                    AND({!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}>40000,{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}<=46667),
                    {!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}*0.15, 
                    IF(
                        {!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}>46667,
                        7000,
                        0
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: That was a mistake. I attempted the formula that Moustafa supplied and it gives me a missing ) error

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
IF({!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}<= 6000,500
IF(
AND({!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}>6000,{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}<= 24000),{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}*0.08,
IF(AND({!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}>24000,{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}<=32000),{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}*0.1,
IF(AND({!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}>3200,{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}<=40000),{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}*0.12,
IF(AND({!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}>40000,{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}<=46667),{!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}*0.15, IF({!$Record.Estimated_Net_Profit_MLS_Wholesale__c}>46667, 7000, 0 ) ) ) ) ) )

Comment: It throws a missing ) error on that one